# how to change the position of text before symbol in Sync Fusion Chart Control ChartSeries

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, syncfusion

I have added below code

```
ChartSeries series1 = new ChartSeries("August",ChartSeriesType.Column);
// Add points to series1.
//....
//....
// Here, the text is given explicitly.

ChartSeries series2 = new ChartSeries("June",ChartSeriesType.Column);
series2.Text = "JuneSales";
```

How to get the 'JuneSales' text first then `ColumnBar` later.
Currently i am getting First the `ColumnBar` and then 'JuneSales' text.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to show the chart image to us, then only we can help you out.

Comment: @Gaurav added image..

Comment: In MSChart the thing is called 'Legend' and it shows 'LegendItems'.

Answer (score 0):

Greetings from Syncfusion,

We have analyzed your query. And we are having IconAlignment property to position the legend item icons. To place the text after the legend symbol, you can set alignment as Right for IconAlignment.

Please find the below code snippet to achieve this requirement,

> chart.Legend.Items[0].IconAlignment = LeftRightAlignment.Right;
>
> chart.Legend.Items[1].IconAlignment = LeftRightAlignment.Right;

Screenshot:[image]

Sample for your reference, can be found from below link,
http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/legendText1476620276

Kindly revert us, if you have any concerns.

Regards,

Baby.